# Laravel 7 - paginate sorted by DESC

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to display posts from the database, but i want to have the latest on top. This means I have to
do this inside of my HomeController.php:

```
$posts = Post::all()->sortByDesc('id');
return view('home', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

But when the site grows up, it might be complicated to find the particular post, so I decided to implement pagination. Unfortunately, pagination only works when I use this statement:

```
$posts = Post::paginate(10);
return view('home', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

When I'm trying to do things like that:

```
$posts = Post::all()->sortByDesc('id')->paginate(10);
```

My site throws an error, no matter what statement I use to display reversed posts and paginate them. Please help me and thank you guys for your every response.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I guess your post can be improved with the error you are running into and what you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `orderBy` and pass 'DESC' to order the result in descending order.

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent has a "latest" method that should help.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset